# Semantics of set() versus Set() versus Set.new

Tags: set, raku, semantics, rakudo

Should `&set`, `Set`, and `Set.new` have different semantics?  If so, why?

Consider the following code:

```raku
my @array = 1, 2;
my @other-array = ([3, 4],);

dd set(@array, @other-array);      #OUTPUT: Set.new(1,2,[3, 4])
dd Set(@array, @other-array);      #OUTPUT: Set.new(1,2,[3, 4])
dd Set.new: @array, @other-array;  #OUTPUT: Set.new([1, 2],[[3, 4],])
```

Is the different output of `Set.new` intentional or the result of a bug in `&set`/`Set`?  (I expected all three to have the output produced by `Set.new` – am I missing something about the intended semantics?)

Comment: TMTOWTDI means multiple different ways to do the same thing. Not one way to do each of many things.

Comment: @raiph Thanks, I just *knew* I'd seen something about Set versus set but I was looking for it on SO rather than on the advent calendar.  But after re-reading that post, it's about a bit different issue where Set.new and set produce the same result and Set() is the odd one out – which makes sense, given that it's a coercer.

Comment: I am a bit confused about why you would want to have a Set of Arrays since afaik Set depends on WHICH semantics, ```dd set([1,2],[1,2],[[3,4],],[[3,4,],])``` giving ```Set.new(2,[3, 4],1,[3, 4])``` and so I would say DO NOT EXPECT SET TO WORK AS YOU EXPECT IF YOU FEED IT ARRAYS

Answer (score 5):

the difference between `set` and `Set.new:` is only [(Un)flattened slurpy paramters](https://docs.raku.org/language/signatures#Signature_literals)`*@a` vs. `**@a`.

```raku
my @array = 1, 2;
my @other-array = ([3, 4],);
-> *@a { say @a }(@array, @other-array);
-> **@a { say @a }(@array, @other-array);
```

`Set()` is [coercion](https://docs.raku.org/language/typesystem#Coercion).

```raku
my Set() $a = (@array, @other-array);
say $a;
-> Set() $a {say $a}( (@array, @other-array) );
say Set(Set(@array, @other-array)), (@array, @other-array).Set;
say Set(class :: { has (@.array, @.other-array);  method Set () { set @!array, @!other-array } }.new( :@array, :@other-array ));
```

Comment: One *could* consider that a bug, though.

Comment: Yeah, I understand the mechanics of how the different behaviors are produced and agree that it comes down to flattening. But as @ElizabethMattijsen said, I don't know if that's intentional or a bug

Comment: Looks like https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/commit/b55a0f166b changed the signature from `+@a` to two candidates, one with `**@a`.  So I think the behaviour with `Set.new` is intentional.  Which brings up the question: perhaps the other two behaviours are wrong?

Comment: Without flattening, isn't the resulting output technically a  ___[Multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset)___?